# Java : Sudoku Game : Checking 3x3 grids for repeated values

Tags: java, sudoku

What this program does :

This program takes values from a class and uses those as the starting values for a Sudoku puzzle. We are to print these out in a typical Sudoku 9x9 grid. The program then prompts the user to give a coordinate point on the grid and a value to put in there. Currently what I am working on is making sure that the values put in by the user are valid to solve this puzzle. Once the puzzle is filled out and there are no longer any repeated values in each column, row, and 3x3 square, the game should end and the output should be "Puzzle Complete".

As of right now, my program checks for repeated values in columns and rows successfully, but I have no idea where to begin for checking each 3x3 square.

The numbers for this puzzle are saved in a 9x9 array.

Basicly : Any tips for how to check for repeated values in each 3x3 part of the array?

Comment: Post the code that you use for the 9x9 grid.

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
    puzzle[i][j] = Integer.toString(Constants.game[i][j]);

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do instead of a big 9x9 array is storing a 3x3 array of 3x3 arrays of numbers. Or do both, for ease of computation (storing 81 more bytes of data (you do use bytes for the fields I hope?) isn't going to cause memory problems in all but the most memory starved devices and I doubt you'd want to play games on such anyway).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you are storing the sudoku board. If you are storing it as a 2D array, you could have your logic identify the 3x3 box the user has chosen to enter the new value and use the code you already have to check a row and column sections.

What you could also have would be to have a collection of 9 sets. Each set would correspond to a specific 3x3 block. So, when the user selects the coordinates of where he/she would like to add the value, you would select the given set and perform an `add` operation in the set.

Since sets do not allow repetition, the `add` method will return `false` if the number already exists in the set. This will also allow you to identify any duplicate values (however, unlike the array option, you would also need to update the set should the user opt to remove values from the 3x3 grid).

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following code about 4 years ago in C to solve the exact same problem, it's as brute-force-y as it looks, though. The int array was a 9x9 grid. The "index" specifies the 0...8th line, 0...8th column, and 0...8th box.

```
int checkBox(int a[][9], int index)
{
    int i, j, isValid = 1;
    int m, n;
    for(i = 3*(index%3) ; isValid && (i < (3*(index%3) + 3)); i++)
    {
        for(j = 3*(index/3); isValid && (j < (3*(index/3) + 3)); j++)
        {
            for(m = (3*(index%3)) ; isValid && (m < (3*(index%3) + 3)); m++)
            {
                for(n = 3*(index/3); isValid && (n < (3*(index/3) + 3)); n++)
                {
                    if(isValid && (a[m][n] == 0) || ((i != m) || (j != n)) && (a[i][j] == a[m][n]))     //select given element and compare others to it
                    {                                                                         //if any element is the same that is not itself then the sudoku is not valid
                        isValid = 0;                                                  //this checks for 3x3 box
                    }                                                               
                }                                               
            }                                                   
        }
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Basically what I did was just manipulate the index until it selected a specific box, and in that box I checked all numbers to see if there's any kind of match. If there is a match, the sudoku is invalid.

In the end, I checked the validity like this:

```
int checkSudoku(int a[][9])                                     //check every row, column and box
{                                                   //if there is no contradiction then it is valid
    int i, isValid = 1;
    for(i = 0; isValid && (i < 9); i++)
    {
        isValid = (checkLine(a, i) && checkColumn(a, i) && checkBox(a, i));
    }
    return isValid;
}
```

Of course, the same concept can be applied to Java, considering it's just array management.